# Pass multiple url parameters in Django on post.save()

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I cannot believe I am still struggling with the simple stuff!!  I need to pass multiple url parameters on form.save() and redirected to my detail view, but am stuck on stupid and have wasted hours on this, please help.  I've included urls as well as detail and list views.  Thank you for your help.

**post_detail view**

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, status='published', publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'press/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'posts': posts})
```

**post_new view**

I stripped all my trial code out to leave only what works, which is - it will post, but doesn't redirect .

```
def post_new(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return render(request, 'press/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, 'press/post_edit.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
```

**detail_view url**

```
url(r'^press/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `redirect`, not `render`, and you need to pass it the values to populate the URL.

```
return redirect('post_detail', kwargs={'year': post.publish.year, 'month': post.publish.month, 'day': post.publish.day, 'post': post.slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the built-in library of django which is redirect,
just import it by "`from django.shortcuts import redirect`"
and you do this:

```
return redirect('url-name',{'posts': posts, 'form': form})
```

hope this will help.